# optical wireless link short range high throughput

Tags: led, wireless, modulation

I am student and I want to realize a wireless optical link in order to have a throughput of 100Mbps max and the distance between the emitter and the receiver is about few centimeters.
I have made my research in the Internet for two weeks,  I found IrDA products. this lead was dispaponting because in theory IrDA technology could attain 96mbps (UFIR protocol), but I found no product having this throughput. laser products are too expensive and they are used for big range (kilometers). I found also the LIFI technology but there is no product responding to my outcome. 
I realized that I can use simple LED (the cost is lower) with modulation, while I was searching in this forum, I found an interesting answer : [Using a LED to transmit data](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24214/using-a-led-to-transmit-data) 
so we can use leds to transmet data with 160mbps and the range is about few centimeters, The problem is I have to use lens and to package them with the emitter and receiver, I wonder why there is no product (not too expensive) ,using led ,I can buy having these characteristics.

Comment: LIFI seems to top at  96 Mbit/s (presently) according to Wikipedia. So assuming you could buy this stuff and interference were not an issue you could do the classic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation with multiple (probably just two) interfaces to achieve 160 Mbit/s.

Comment: Your requirements are pretty steep! What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for your answers ^^
I want to achieve a LED-FSO system with 100mbps max and short range (few centimeters)
concretely, the system contains one emitter and a lot of receivers, the emitter moves in front of each receiver to transfer data

Comment: The answer is most likely one of "supply vs demand." If the demand is low, the price will be high, if available, or not available at all.

Comment: yes I agree with you Guill